# Connect Twilio phone number with Twiml app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-twiml

When buy a new number from twilio and connecting it with sms url to recieve SMS reply from user we do the following:

```
twilio.object.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create(
  :phone_number => number,
  :sms_url => url
 )
```

but when change this url we have to go through all numbers and change the SMS url so we create a Twiml app.

**Question is:**
Can we connect phone number when buy it to Twiml app something like:

```
twilio.object.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create(
  :phone_number => number,
  :twiml_sid => sid  // that what we are trying to achieve
 )
```

or its only `sms_url` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can absolutely do this.  Just set the VoiceApplicationSid parameter when creating the new phone number:

```
$number = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->create(array(
  "FriendlyName" => "My Company Line",
  "VoiceApplicationSid" => "APXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "PhoneNumber" => "+15105647903"
));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are correct, i found it and i added an answer for ruby and using sms_application_sid, will accept the answer thought

Comment: Hi Devin, can you please check my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370533/twiml-app-invoke-aws-lambda-when-user-replies-stop-start-for-twilio-number

Answer (score 0):

According to Twilio Documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post-optional-parameters):

under Optional Paramters you can find `SmsApplicationSid` and `VoiceApplicationSid` setting it to Twiml app SID will use the SMS url or Voice url according to which service you want to handle responce for, following should be working:

```
twilio.object.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create(
 :phone_number => number,
 :sms_application_sid => sid
)
```